# Workbooks.Activate not working on some computers

Tags: vba, excel

I ran into a strange Excel 2013 VBA behavior today and felt posting the solution to the problem may help someone else in the future. 
The following command worked fine on my computer and most others but one user would get an error message.  I'm using Windows 7.

`Workbooks("Book1").Activate`

Comment: What error message? Is Book1 open? Post more of your code.

Comment: Is `Book1` a saved workbook ?

Comment: Good questions - thanks. I should have been more specific.  The code is in Book1 which has previously been saved.  It created a second Book with an unknown name.  So that second book was activated upon creation.  Then to switch back to the original Book1 was where the Workbooks.Activate command was not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was that the other user has 'extensions for known file types' shown.  By default Windows wants to hide those.  In order to get the code to work properly on all machines, I had to include the file extension in the code as shown below.  When a new workbook is created and has not yet been saved, it does not need a file extension included in this command as it is not yet determined.

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but this may be related to a setting in "Folder options" of Windows Explorer.

On the View tab there is an option "Hide extensions for known file types" - this will affect how you can refer to workbooks by name in VBA.

EDIT: seems you got there already!

Comment: Thanks Tim. I should have just posted the question when I first ran into it. I took me viewing his screen remotely (different site) to start moving toward the answer.  You nailed it without any help!  I looked for a similar problem and solution on this site before digging into it which is why I decided to post the question and answer for others.

Answer (score -1):

I've already had the file extensions enabled but it didn't work. I fixed by forcing the file and sheet to activate.

Example (while the files are still open):

```
 Windows("file2.xlsm").Activate
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
```

I know that `Activate` and `Select` are inneficient, but if it works..